# Как использовать несколько условий в Filter

Tags: powershell

А как использовать в фильтре несколько условий так, как это делается в выражении where?  **Get-mailboxes | Where {$_.Name -like '[a-d]*'}**

В Фильтре такое не работает **Get-mailboxes -Filter {$_.Name -like '[a-d]*'}** а очень нужно.
То есть нужно вывести всех кто начинается от a до d ...

Comment: а в чем проблема Filter заменить на Where ?

Comment: большое количество данных, под 10 тысяч, реально ооочень медленно работает. при том инфра современная, 2016 exch сервера и железо.

Answer (score 1):

пока вижу только один способ:

```
Get-Mailbox  -Filter {DisplayName -like 'a*' -or DisplayName -like 'b*' -or DisplayName -like 'c*' -or DisplayName -like 'd*' -or DisplayName -like 'e*'}
```